# User-specific ABAP breakpoint acts weird

Tags: abap, breakpoints

Why the statement

```
BREAK-POINT 'my username'.
```

affects not only me but other users too? Am I insane? Maybe this is a problem of permissions or any other reason? Can anybody explain me?

This statement is located in method body in class which implements BAdI.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to use break points only for your username, you have to use it like this:

```
BREAK username.
```

If you use

```
BREAK-POINT.
```

it is going to affect everyone.

The **actual meaning** of `BREAK-POINT 'my username'.` is completely different (comment from vwegert):

> See [the documentation of BREAK-POINT](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapbreak-point.htm) - you've been using your user name as a log text

Comment: Also see http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABAPBREAK-POINT.htm#&ABAP_ADDITION_2@2@ - you've been using your user name as a log text.

Comment: Thanks for documentation vwegert. I also do appriciate that.

Answer (score 2):

Not the direct answer for your question, but maybe also helpful:

In transaction `SAAB` you can define a checkpoint group (e.g. `Z_MYbreaks`).
Then you can use the following command:

```
BREAK-POINT ID Z_MYbreaks.
```

The breakpoint will have no effect, unless you activate it in transaction `SAAB`. The advantage over `break USERID`:

- Can can (de)activate it without a code change (you could transport it to the productive system and activate it only, when you want to test something).
- It can be ativated by and for everybody, not only for the one user id in the `break`-command. (Sure: you need the authorization)

Details can be found at

- http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABAPBREAK-POINT.htm#&ABAP_ADDITION_1@1@
- http://www.saptechnical.com/Tutorials/ABAP/CheckpointGroup/Index.htm